# Best way to sync gdata without pulling every X minutes?

Tags: python, gdata

What is the most effective way to sync a local database with say Google Documents list? Right now I am pulling every minute and look for updated docs:

```
client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient(source='Test')
token =     gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=xxx,client_secret=yyy, etc etc)
token.authorize(client)
updated_min = '2012-01-19T12:32:12'
docs = client.GetDocList(uri='/feeds/default/private/full?
showfolders=true&showdeleted=true&max_results=999&edited-min='+updated_min)
```

Is there any way to optimize resources by having a persistent connection or without having to authorize the client in every pull? or is there any push-alike method like IMAP IDLE?

Thanks!!!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no official methods provided, but Google is using XMPP internally for its Chrome database sync. PS, our apps also have this same need and using pulling mechanism to sync the data.

Answer (score 0):

No

without authorizing you will not be able to do this!!!

because our apps have the same need and using pulling mechanism to sync the data